# CSV Export missing the custom column field added by renderer magento

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, grid, export, renderer

Because my grid has a problem when join table, so I used renderer to show data like this

```
'brand' => array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('advr')->__('Brand'),
            'column_css_class' => 'nobr',
            'renderer' => 'Mirasvit_Advr_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_Brand',
        ),
```

Renderer/Brand.php

```
<?php
class Vendor_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_Brand extends 
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
public function render(Varien_Object $row)
{

    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($row->getIncrementId());
    $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
    $brand = array();
    foreach ($items as $i){
        $productId = $i->getProductId();
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
        $brand[] = $product->getAttributeText('brand');
    }
    return implode(',', $brand);
}

public function renderExport(Varien_Object $row) {
    return $this->render($row);
}
}
?>
```

but it can not get this column in csv file. Anyone know how to fix it? Help me please, thanks

Comment: add index to brand column

Comment: I tried, but not work.

Comment: can you add code of  _prepareCollection()

Comment: thank you. I found a solution to fix it in export function, now it can get data of this column in csv file

Comment: that's great...